# Nissan Qashqai "Test Mode": What does the data mean?

Tags: nissan, diagnostics, dtc

I learned about a "test mode" for the display, which can be used for diagnostics, without an obd reader.

I managed to get inside the test mode, but I am baffled by the data and am not sure what it means.

Visually it looks like this:

[image]

The line where it says "Part No BR51C" can be changed by pressing a button.

The particular part in question seems to be a spark plug. But what is this trying to tell me? Why is a random part number written?

Other lines contain the following information:

- dtcs none (I guess no error codes?)
- EE 01
- NROM 0117
- ROM 0117
- A14 00
- WI Code CD
- Port P -00
- and so on

Most of these things, except the part number, I can not find on google.
What would you expect these lines to mean and why would a random part number be listed?

I checked some YouTube videos where other parts are displayed. Is it trying to tell me, that my spark plugs are gone (which I suspect anyway)?

Comment: Just a small question: why do you think Nissan engineers will publish internal test codes?

Comment: I assumed that this is something for me or my mechanic to view, because it also contains other information like oil level. So the incomprehensible codes are just that? Incomprehensible for anyone outside Nissan? What about the random part number? What might be the reason for it?

Comment: Just random to you, may well be fine for the Nissan engineers... Why don't you just use a decent OBD reader to get the codes that may well confirm your spark plug issue.

Comment: But why embed it in the dash display, if it is not intended for the end user? I thought this is diagnostics for people, who don't have a tool (end users). Although apparently not.

Comment: So, you found this in the User manual or on Youtube? I have seen people enter low level modes on many items and completely screw them...

Comment: On youtube, but I thought that it might be described somewhere in the user manual. But yeah, I ordered an odb scanner. I thought I might get away with this diagnosis.

Comment: So, you are happy to risk the value of your vehicle based on a youtube video... prepared to walk to work tomorrow?  I spent quite a sum of money on a good reader for my car and yes, it has paid for itself...

Comment: Unfortunately I will be walking anyway.